# Table column styling with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table on my website and i am trying to style it with jquery. the code i am using works fine with normal table but if in a column two cells are merged it destroys the style. I want 1 column to be coloured and one column blank

jquery code

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#tab-table').find("table").addClass('s-table');
    $(".s-table tr td:nth-child(2n+1)").css("background-color","#d1deec");
});
```

[link to fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k5yZ9/)

Comment: Why are you styling in jQuery and not CSS?

Comment: As i am using CMS and there are alot of tables on the web site to style it with css i need to use alot of classes which i dont want, so i am trying to make it dynamic so if a new table is added it takes the style automatically. I hope it make sense

Comment: Yes but you can do that in CSS?

Comment: can you provide a short example?

Comment: I was messing with CSS there and couldnt get it working - it'll just use nth/eq/odd etc and ignore if merged cells.. dont think possible without loops..

Comment: Well in that case, I apologies! I was wrong.

Comment: @BeatAlex no need appologies - you are 100% correct that a CSS solution would be way better than JQuery one, but I dont think it is the case here..

Comment: @JFit see my CSS answer :)

Comment: Yes +1 to your answer, its nice - but please show in a fiddle.. I'd like to learn more about it.

Comment: oki, here : http://fiddle.jshell.net/4ftkz/ thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a loop (if the merged cells will always stay the same..

see fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/jFIT/k5yZ9/4/

```
$("table tr:not(:first)").each(function() {
 if($(this).find('td').length == 7)
 {
    //can replace with array 2/4/6
   $(this).find('td:nth-child(2)').css("background-color","#d1deec");
 }
 else   
 {
    // 3/5/7
$(this).find('td:nth-child(3)').css("background-color","#d1deec");
 }
 //loop array
});
```

**Update**

http://jsfiddle.net/jFIT/k5yZ9/6/

Using array:

```
$("table tr:not(:first)").each(function () {
 var arr = [];
 var $this = $(this);
 if ($(this).find('td').length == 7) {
     arr.push(2, 4, 6);
 } else {
     arr.push(3, 5, 7);
 }
 $.each(arr, function (ind, val) {
     $this.find('td:nth-child(' + val + ')').css("background-color", "#d1deec");
 });
});
```

Comment: basic CSS works easily too if you use the colgroup/col markup :)

Comment: @UmarKhan No problem - Just be weary if the columns and grouping changes you'll need to revisit this code.

Answer (score 2):

CSS can help you to draw colonnes background-colors if you use proper markup :

```
<colgroup>
<col/>
<col/>
</colgroup>
```

and then basicly apply :

`col {background:#789 url(image.png);}`

A mixed of background in col , and rgba colors in cells can give you this : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/ybDhH/

Else , if you do not have hands on markup, trick it and do it from headers cells.
You could use some tricks with `box-shadow` or `pseudo-element` from header cells and `overflow` on `table`.
**`Pseudo-element` technic** : 
http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/dDwmf

and  **`box-shadow` technic:** http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/xqALu

Comment: Hi Can you show this in a fiddle? Very interested in this.

Comment: yep, wich one should i use to start with ?

Comment: Just the most basic, I understand you will need to change markup but maybe throw it into the fiddle we were working on above from OP.. http://jsfiddle.net/jFIT/k5yZ9/4/

Comment: without class do col:nth-child(even) {background:#d1deec}